# Check Gzip enabled or not of a website using PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I am creating an SEO analyzer. One part of it is to find whether a website has gzip enabled or not.

I found that gzip can be done either by **.htaccess** or in apache or Nginx. So how can i find whether entered website has gzip enabled or not?

Also when i open a website like this : `www.example.com/.htaccess` it is giving me a error saying "`permission denied`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok thank you guys. I have written the code to check gzip of a website. Here it is...

```
<?php
$headers = get_headers("http://www.example.com", 1);
echo $headers['Content-Encoding'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try analyzing headers with `getallheaders`. Look for something like: `Content-Encoding`
More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

And here is example code:

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    if ($name == 'Content-Encoding') {
        echo 'Encoding is: ' . $value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all:
`.htaccess` should be only be accessible through the file system, for example through ftp.

As for the `gzip` detection, check the response header for: `Content-Encoding gzip`

Answer (score -1):

htaccess is a hidden system file so you cannot access it, usually you would use `phpinfo();` to look at your php settings.

Comment: OPs question is to how to find whteher a given remote url is enabled for gzip compression

Comment: yes, I'm not checking a site on localserver. I need to check gzip of another website